# I can't open a chat Intent by pressing a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't open a new Intent by a button but only in listview I followed a guide but it solved it listview and I need a normal click where is the problem in my code

The code only works with the listview...

```
 buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postition, long id){



                       String curentgruopname = parent.getItemAtPosition(postition).toString();
                       Intent groupchatintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , buttonaddactivity.class);
                       groupchatintent.putExtra("groupname", curentgruopname);

                       startActivity(groupchatintent);



                   }
                        });
```

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postition, long id) {

                String curentgruopname = parent.getItemAtPosition(postition).toString();
                Intent groupchatintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , buttonaddactivity.class);
                groupchatintent.putExtra("groupname", curentgruopname);

                startActivity(groupchatintent);


            }
        });
```

Comment: it looks strange to me using 

 buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){

are you sure it is the same as View.OnClickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works when you initialize the OnClicklistener in the OnCreate Method.

Here is an Example:

```
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
}

View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(testActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: please share your complete class. Copy my version and test it, it works in my Example.